# Where does Xcode save the program's executable files or equivalent files?

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to do a I/O redirection to get input into my program from a file. I need to know where the executable file is located to enter it into the terminal. I'm on a mac, using Xcode, in C. Also, I can only use the terminal to get the input.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to Xcode > Preferences > Locations:

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Which folder and file is the executable file in?

Comment: and there go to the most intuitive <APPNAME-someid>/Build/Products/Debug/

Comment: Perfect, thanks! This helped me to find it after an update :)

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you are looking for `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`.
In newer versions of Mac OS X, to get to the Library folder, open up Finder, then press "Go" in the menu bar. Once the menu is open, press the Option(alt) key, and Library should appear.
Hope this helps!