# xcode command line app - where is the executable code?

Tags: xcode

I'm writing a small command line tool/app in Xcode 6.  After a steep learning curve (that I'm still climbing) I've got my code working in main.m without errors.  My question is: does Xcode build some executable code that I can run from the command line inside a Terminal?  I've tried "Build" and "Run & Build" but I don't see where any executable code is created.  I'm very new at Xcode and need some help.  I'm running OS X 10.9.5 and Xcode 6.1.1 on a Mac Mini.

If viewing my code would be useful, let me know and I'll put it up.

Thanks for any assistance.

Kevin H.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does Xcode save the program's executable files or equivalent files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521614/where-does-xcode-save-the-programs-executable-files-or-equivalent-files)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's hidden very well. In Xcode 6, when you build an app, there is a folder "Products" in the project navigator (left pane). The name of your project will be there too. Right click, and select "show in finder". It will show you an obscure folder hidden deep in your OS X Library where the executable is located.

Comment: Non Plus Ultra, thanks for the useful answer.  I did find the executable where you said it would be.  Yes, it's a very obscure location.  A couple of questions:  1) can I relocate the executable to a friendly location?  2) can I direct Xcode to build the executable someplace else?  3) can I somehow run the executable directly form the command line?  Thanks!  Kevin H.

Comment: 1) I guess you can
2) see below ;)
3) absolutely. it's standalone.

Comment: That trick seems to not work anymore: the finder opens to the repo instead, which contains the `product` folder.

Answer (score 14):

To copy the executable to a more convenient location each time you compile go into the project settings and select the Build Phase.

Type in a absolute location such as: ~/Documents/dev/temp.  (It does recognize ~ as the current users home directory)

Then Press the '+' Button Under the 'Copy Files' Section and Select Your File (Select Your executable under the Products Folder)

Deselect the 'Copy only when installing' button.  Then build and it should be at that location.

To launch just open the terminal app and go to that location.  The executable should run unless there are dynamic libraries it calls that are not in the lib path.

Hope this helps

Comment: I also had to check the "Sign code" checkbox, otherwise the build would fail. Also, be careful. I pointed it towards my source code folder (because I wanted the executable in the same directory as my source code) and it was cleared while building. So bye bye source code :-/

Comment: `${PROJECT_DIR}/bin` worked for me in the “Absolute Path” destination box

Answer (score 7):

The binary is in a folder under **/Users/Username/Library**.
Something like:

```
/Users/<Username>/Library//Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Products/Debug/<ProjectName>
```

You can easily find it with this command:

```
find /Users/<Username>/Library/ -name "<ProjectName>"
```

replace "Username" and "ProjectName" accordingly to reflect your environment.

Answer (score 0):

"Find" works, but you could also view the build log output and look for "CreateBuildDirectory" and copy the path from there.

Example below: [image: sample build log output with path highlighted]

In Xcode 14 the path is nested under the line that says "Create build directory $(DERIVED_DATA_DIR)", but you can see the full path by expanding the icon on the right of the output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 15**

You can find the terminal executable by going to the **Product** menu and selecting **Show Build Folder in Finder**.