# Displaying XCode C++ Output in Separate Screen

Tags: c++

I am looking for a way to display the output from a C++ program in a separate window. I am just hoping someone could point me in the right direction. Just running a simple count statement and displaying that on a separate pop up screen would be awesome and I could run with it from there.
To hopefully help clarify a little.. Something similar to this would work http://wwww.youtube.com/watch?v=IXtm7cI21vM

Comment: To hopefully help clarify a little.. Something similar to this would work
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IXtm7cI21vM

Comment: Run your program from terminal, without XCode. Here is how to find out where is the executable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521614/where-does-xcode-save-the-programs-executable-files-or-equivalent-files